# PropertyBusinessObject with enumeration property

Tags: codenameone

One of my entities has a `Property` which is a `Property<State, WorkshopStatus>` declared here :

```
public final Property<State, WorkshopStatus> status = new Property<>("status", State.class);
```

But when I try to get the value of this properties, I caught a `ClassCastException`, because the property's value is a `String` which cannot be cast to an `State` enum.
Is enum properties supported by Codename One ?

Comment: If it isn't supported it should work but we need to go over the individual use cases. How did you populate the object? What's the stack trace of the exception? You might need to define a `MapAdapter` instance to map the property enum instance to String/visa versa.

Comment: The object is populated from a `Rest` call and a `getAsProperties(State.class)`. The exception come from the getter I've set in the entity which call the `get()` from the property, so it doesn't come from the populate. The `MapAdapter` do the trick, thanks !

Comment: Just to confirm: this resolved using `MapAdapter`?

Comment: Yes, using ´MapAdapter´ solved my problem